# I'm not seeing ng-repeat data on browser Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, view, angularjs-ng-repeat

For some reason I'm not visualizing data in the browser.

Here a pic of my console:

[image]

Inside p tag I am expecting to see retrieved data.

Here is the view:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="voce in voices">
    <p style="color:#000;">{{voce.series}}</p>
</div>
```

Here is the controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$q,voci) {

var promise = voci.getVoices();

promise.then(function(data){
    $scope.voices = data;
    console.log($scope.voices);
});

});
```

Here is the service voci:

```
app.service('voci', function ($http,$q) {

var deferred = $q.defer(); 

$http.get('urldata.json').then(function(data)
{
    deferred.resolve(data);
});

this.getVoices = function(){
    return deferred.promise;
};

})
```

Output of console.log $scope.voices:

[image]

I am using ngroute to associate views and controller, in the main module:

```
var app = angular.module('generaPreventivoApp', [
'ngAnimate',
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngRoute',
'ngSanitize'
  ])

  .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'main'
  })
  .when('/about', {
    templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
    controller: 'AboutCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'about'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
   $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
  });
```

Why this kind of problem? Thank you

Comment: Are you getting any output in `console.log($scope.voices);` ?

Comment: What does the data look like? We can't help without a [mcve]

Comment: Does the $http.get return data from the promise? Have you declared the controller in the markup ?

Comment: yes i see the object scope.voices, i update the console output i nthe main description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="voce in voices.data">
    <p style="color:#000;">{{voce.series}}</p>
</div>
```

or:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$q,voci) {

var promise = voci.getVoices();

promise.then(function(data){
    $scope.voices = data.data;
    console.log($scope.voices);
});

});
```